# Halt grunt server from terminal

Tags: terminal, gruntjs, yeoman

I've installed and am exploring Yeoman but one thing that I can't seem to find an answer to is, how do I halt the grunt server from running?

Is this something that can be done from the terminal? It just sits and waits.

Comment: Typically `ctrl+c` halts anything in the terminal.

Comment: @JasonEarly could you make your comment into an answer? That way he can accept it as it was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You can stop it with ctrl + c in terminal
- If it's a task that is running in background you can find his process
  id (pid) with ps aux | grep grunt and then kill it with kill {pid}